# How does key exchange work? Using symmetric algorithm such as AES

Tags: encryption, key-management, aes

I was wondering how does the sender give the encrypted file and the key to the receiver securely? Particularly on situations where the sender doesnt meet with the receiver (through email or through flash drive). What form or file form does the key look like in real world situations?

Comment: Can you please narrow down your question to a specific use case? There are various forms a key can be exchanged and one important aspect is if both peers have a bidirectional communication as in case of TLS or IPSec or if there is only an unidirectional communication as in case of mail. Also, please read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) about key exchange and ask the parts in more detail which you don't understand in this article - there is no need to replicate here what is already well written online.

Answer (score 0):

It obviously can't be a single file containing the key. No matter what form such file takes, both the receiver and the perpetrator would have the same information.

Therefore, without physically meeting each other, *Alice* and *Bob* would need to use a **method** to establish the shared secret. Such as the [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), among others.